# "Uncaught ReferenceError _ is not defined" while using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using underscore.js in my code, I'm getting this weird error even though `<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>` is already included in my HTML and, the code still works like a charm despite of it. So what's causing my error?

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Is it from JS code executing _before_ Underscore is included?

Comment: Nope, it only happens when I call an underscore function. Like, if my code has `_.range(6)`, it will work, but spitting the error nonetheless.